Why does the Schwarzschild solution describe a black hole?
I recently started studying general relativity and came across the following problem. Schwarzschild's solution is a solution to Einstein's equations in a vacuum, with a zero energy-momentum tensor. As far as I know, Schwarzschild did not consider any physical system (a star or a black hole) when he was looking for this solution, he was simply looking for a spherically symmetric solution (a purely mathematical problem). How did it happen that this solution describes a black hole? Is the energy-momentum tensor for a black hole equal to 0? Yes, it is equal to 0 where there is no mass, but the mass is concentrated somewhere. It seemed to me that in order to find a metric around a black hole, one should take the energy-momentum tensor equal to the delta function (in the sense that all the mass is at the origin, at one point). And then solve Einstein's equations with such an energy-momentum tensor (it will no longer be zero).
For example, there is a problem of solving the Einstein equations for a spherically symmetric star, where the energy-momentum tensor will be equal to 0 at $r>R$ (radius of the star), but at $r<R$ it will be non-zero, depending on the density and pressure at the particular point (usually the ideal fluid model is used). From this problem one can get the Oppenheimer-Volkoff equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation). And in this case, I understand the physical formulation of the problem, it is clear why the energy-momentum tensor is what it is.
But for a black hole?

Once a massive object can bend other objects' path (including light), then logically enough mass concentrated in a tight volume will cause any object (including light) to orbit/spiral towards this object, right?

I believe the OP is asking:why do objects with radii smaller than their Scharzwild radii become black holes.Not sure if im correct tho.Qubek feel free to comment below.

In the Wikipedia article Schwarzschild metric there is some information about the  singularities in the Schwarzschild's solution as they were analyzed later by other scientists. The interpretation of the solution as a black hole came only decades later.

@Qubek Your question is based on a typical misconception that mass/energy necessarily corresponds to a finite stress-energy tensor.  It doesn’t. The kinetic energy doesn’t curve spacetime. When an object (a particle of the original star matter) falls to the horizon, the kinetic energy of this particle increases due to the mass defect. The coordinate mass of the particle tends to zero and all energy becomes kinetic at the horizon where the star matter remains forever in our view. The total energy conserves during the collapse giving mass to the black hole, but the stress-energy vanishes.

Safesphere At $r = r_S$ I obtain a finite energy density $\rho_S=\frac{3 M c^2}{4\pi r_S^3}$ and a pressure, the graph of which is a vertical half line starting at zero and going to infinity.

Related: How do we know the Schwarzschild solution contains an object of mass $M$?

@JanG You are overlooking the fact that the inner radius is timelike, so the spatial radius of the horizon is zero and the volume is zero too. So the energy density in the Schwarzschild coordinates diverges at the horizon. The confusion is caused by the radius defined as the reduced circumference. The problem with this definition is that it is always spacelike while the inner radial interval is timelike. This results in errors while calculating distances and volumes.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/829524/829681#comment1871637_829681

@safesphere You misunderstood my comment. The fact that expression for energy density at the event horizon is identical to constant energy density of a Euclidean sphere is really a coincidence. I entirely agree with you that there is no interior volume. The result I was talking about came from Schwarzschild's interior solution in the limit of r_S/R going to 1 (see Appendix in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/757634/281096).

@safesphere "So the energy density diverges in the Schwarzschild coordinates". Since t is spatial and r is temporal, shouldn't the energy density behave like pressure and the pressure like energy density? That would reconcile our views.

@JanG The key is that the energy density diverges in the Schwarzschild coordinates, but not locally and thus not physically. For example, if you jump in and I follow you the next day, then you and I never physically meet at a close distance. At the horizon we would see ourselves separated by billions of miles. However a remote  external observer whose coordinates are approximately Schwarzschild would see as if I practically have caught up with you near the horizon (due to the gravitational length contraction in his coordinates).  So he sees the density diverging while locally it doesn’t.

@safesphere That makes sense to me.  It sounds like you already jumped into BH and came back to give this testimony. Great explaining.

The Schwarzschild solution is not specifically for a black hole, although it does cover that. The Schwarzschild solution is a spherically symmetric vacuum solution. So it covers the vacuum region outside of any spherically symmetric distribution of matter. This includes ordinary (non-rotating) planets and stars. A black hole is just a limiting case of this spacetime as the areal radius of the outer surface goes to zero.

This is due to Birkhoff's theorem:

In general relativity, Birkhoff's theorem states that any spherically symmetric solution of the vacuum field equations must be static and asymptotically flat. This means that the exterior solution (i.e. the spacetime outside of a spherical, nonrotating, gravitating body) must be given by the Schwarzschild metric.

The point is that regardless of what the mass distribution of body is, as long as it is spherically symmetric outside the body the metric will be the Schwarzschild metric. Whether it's a star with a non-zero volume or a delta function mass at $r = 0$ makes no difference.
For completeness we should note that the Schwarzschild black hole does not have a delta mass at $r = 0$. In fact the point $r = 0$ is not part of the manifold at all. The mass in the Schwarzschild metric is a geometrical property called the ADM mass.

@JanG which equation (9)? That link goes to a seemingly unrelated question and has no numbered equations.

@Triatticus Thank you for pointing out my mistake. It should be https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/679431/281096 . I mean equations (8) and (9).

Maybe not quite correct? I have indeed found a static spherically symmetric vacuum solution that is not asymptotically flat, see equation (9) in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/679431/281096 (link corrected). Asymptotic flatness requires zero pressure as a boundary condition on the surface of a perfect fluid sphere.

@JanG You're (knowingly) using a nonstandard definition of "vacuum". In the context of Birkhoff's theorem, and all GR literature I'm familiar with, "vacuum" definitionally refers to the stress-energy being identically zero. Note that this isn't a claim about what a vacuum "really" is, but an agreed-upon definition so that we know what each other mean when using the word.

@John Rennie +1, though there do exist senses in which the Schwarzschild metric is indeed a distributional solution to a set of PDE's induced by Einstein's equations with a delta function energy density source at $r = 0$. See Theorem 6 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.00967

@jawheele. An empty universe is an oxymoron, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/787992/281096. In his book The Special and the General Theory, fifth edition, 1954, https://www.relativitybook.com/lander, in the Chapter The Concept of Space in the General Theory of Relativity, Einstein says "There is no such thing as an empty space, that is a space without field." By space he means spacetime, and by field matter (there is no gravitational field in GR). In my understanding the so-called vacuum solution is valid only in the matter free part of spacetime.

@JanG Whether there exists any region in the physical universe entirely devoid of matter or not is immaterial to how the term "vacuum" is defined and interpreted in GR. At the very heart of physics is working in idealized scenarios to provide equations that can be solved and interpreting those solutions only as approximating reality sufficiently well for application's purposes in certain regimes.

@jawheele In physics, solving a differential equation actually means solving an initial value problem. If the energy tensor $T$ is globally identically zero, then you cannot set any physical boundary conditions. Which of metrics satisfying the equation $G=0$ is then called the solution depends on your choice.

@JanG The vacuum initial value problem is a rich and deeply studied subject in GR (a fundamental reference is https://www.amazon.com/Global-Nonlinear-Stability-Minkowski-Space/dp/0691087776, or the later developments in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.3880), and one can set reasonable initial conditions to describe a myriad of physical situations of interest. It is fundamental, for example, to modeling dynamics of gravitational waves. Note that any degrees of freedom available when specifying boundary conditions in vacuum are also present when one includes matter.

The Schwarzschild solution yields a region of spacetime which nothing inside it can escape outside it unless causality is broken. The geodesics just do not allow for that (see figure). The light cones past the event horizon are tilted in a way that gives you no way out. This is the definition of a black hole.


It should be mentioned that this is only a limiting case: There is a version of the Schwarzschild solution for bodies such that the Schwarzschild radius lies inside the body. In this case, we do not have a black hole region (otherwise, no spherically symmetric objects could exist, lest they all immediately form a black hole and collapse).

@paulina, could you give us the reference for this version?

@JanG the keyword is "interior solutions". Robert M. Wald spends a few pages on it in his textbook on General Relativity.

@paulina Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you speak of interior solutions for compactness ratio 8/9<r_S/R<1.

To put paulina’s comment differently, any body of mass has a hypothetical Schwarzschild radius. If the actual radius is bigger than the Schwarzschild radius then there won’t be a black hole. This is why what matters most is really the density of the matter, not the mass of the matter. Meaning how concentrated the matter is.

Lots of good answer, but everything I know about blackholes I learned from Kip Thorne, and since he's world famous, he's on YouTube$^{1, 2, 3}$.
He explains that a blackhole doesn't contain matter. The in-falling material crosses the horizon, and then the singularity is point in its future, when it is destroyed.
The singularity contains all the non-zero $G_{\mu, \nu}$ as a topological defect in space-time (it's not part of space-time anymore), and the Schwarzschild solution is the warped-space time that cloaks that and connects it back to asymptotic Minkowski space.
All the mass/energy of to progenitor star now resides in the warped space-time surrounding the singularity. (I note that Kip always says warped---because it's not flat, but as you pointed out: it's a vacuum solution with zero curvature (via the Einstein tensor).
[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oj1AfkPQa6M&list=PLFJr3pJl27pItxUFeZlx98GQzl-5UBroJ&index=10
[2] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiocBE51yuc&list=PLFJr3pJl27pItxUFeZlx98GQzl-5UBroJ
[3] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThuFewi-mRM&list=PLFJr3pJl27pItxUFeZlx98GQzl-5UBroJ&index=3
